# Term for a phrase that gives scope to a definite article?

Tags: grammar, phrases, definite-articles

Is there a grammatical term for a phrase that supplies the scope for a definite article?  Like "the man ***in the moon***" or "the book ***on the shelf***"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *restrictive* phrase.

> In semantics, a modifier is said to be restrictive (or defining) if it restricts the reference of its head.[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictiveness) For example, in "the red car is fancier than the blue one", red and blue are restrictive, because they restrict which cars car and one are referring to. ("The car is fancier than the one" would make little sense.) By contrast, in "John's beautiful mother", beautiful is non-restrictive; "John's mother" identifies her sufficiently, whereas "beautiful" only serves to add more information.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictiveness)

In your examples, *in the moon* restricts the scope of *the man*, and *on the shelf* restricts the scope of *the book*.

However, this isn't specific to head phrases containing the definite article. They would still be considered restrictive even if the head phrase contained an indefinite article.